# Build android CopperheadOS for sailfish (AOSP) issue

Tags: android, android-source, ninja

I am not able to build the source tree whith

make target-files-package -j20

results into :

```
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory `.'
[  0% 5/42089] build out/target/product/marlin/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.local.tmp
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "m4 -s system/sepolicy/file_contexts out/target/product/marlin/obj/ETC/sectxfile_nl_intermediates/sectxfile_nl > out/target/product/marlin/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.local.tmp"
/bin/bash: m4: command not found
[  0% 5/42089] build out/target/product/marlin/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.device.tmp
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "m4 -s  device/google/marlin/sepolicy/file_contexts out/target/product/marlin/obj/ETC/sectxfile_nl_intermediates/sectxfile_nl > out/target/product/marlin/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.device.tmp"
/bin/bash: m4: command not found
[  0% 5/42089] Lex: checkpolicy <= external/selinux/libsepol/cil/src/cil_lexer.l
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex/flex-2.5.39 -oout/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libsepol_intermediates/cil/src/cil_lexer.c external/selinux/libsepol/cil/src/cil_lexer.l"
flex-2.5.39: fatal internal error, exec of /usr/bin/m4 failed
[  0% 5/42089] host Executable: mkbootfs (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkbootfs_intermediates/mkbootfs)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems *m4* is not installed on your system. If you're running Ubuntu, execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install m4
```